# C++ avoiding newline with cout <<

Tags: c++, io, ostream

How could I avoid the newline in this code..

```
void ListEl::display() {
    BaseEl::display();
    cout << " Asis: " << anemnesis << endl;
}
```

here is BaseEl::display()

```
void BaseEl::display() {
    cout << "P: " << priority << "\tN: " <<  name << endl;
}
```

it prints always the output of `BaseEl::display();` then a newline, and then the `" Asis: " << anemnesis << endl;`

I tried `cout << BaseEl::display() << " Asis: " << anemnesis << endl;` but it didnt work neither

Comment: Please add the code of `BaseEl::display()`.

Comment: By not writing `endl` ?

Comment: maybe because BaseEl::display(); outputs itself a std::endl?

Comment: _"it prints always the output of `BaseEl::display();` then a newline"_ No, the newline is part of the output of `BaseEl::display()`

Comment: OK, now you've updated the question with the code of `BaseEl::display()` can't you figure it out for yourself?!

Comment: @JonathanWakely could you NOT answer and stop whinging? Just take charge of other questions and let others help..

Comment: @ZelelB: But then, you could have looked up the meaning of `std::endl`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot fix this without modifying `BaseEl::display()` to stop producing new line at the end of the output.

In general, it is a bad idea to add `endl` to your own output. Let the caller do that if he needs a newline.

Note that a more C++-like approach to output of your own classes is providing an implementation of `operator <<` for the output. If you want virtual dispatch with it, provide an implementation at the level of the base class, and add a virtual member function for derived classes to override:

```
class BaseEl {
protected:
    virtual void writeToStream(ostream& ostr) const;
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& ostr, const BaseEl& val);
};
class ListEl : public BaseEl {
protected:
    virtual void writeToStream(ostream& ostr) const;
};

ostream& operator << (ostream& ostr, const BaseEl& val) {
    val.writeToStream(ostr);
    return ostr;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Answer

The meaning of `endl` is to print a newline-character and flush the output buffer. Hence you need to remove it from where you do not want a newline character.

Flushing the output buffers excessively can lead to performance loss and is normally not needed to be done manually, so as a general rule, avoid `endl` (unless, as said, you explicitly want to newline and flush).

In short, as general rules:

- *to flush*: use `std::flush`
- *to newline*: use `'\n'` or append it to your string: `"foobar!\n"`
- *both*: use `std::endl`

#### Advice

In C++, object serialization is done through overloading `operator<<` and `operator>>`, such that you can write

```
ListEl mylist;
std::cout << "The list: " << mylist << '\n';
```

Canonically, for output, it looks like this:

```
class Foobar {
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, Foobar const &);    
};

// might go into implementation file
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, Foobar const &foobar) {
    // print work
    ....

    // Do not forget to return the stream
    return os;
}
```

Letting that operator be a `friend` is a consequence of `operator<<(std::ostream &, Foobar const&)` not being `inline`-able within `Foobar`. If the print-function does not need access to private members, skip the `friend`.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `endl` from `BaseEl::display()` or do as @dasblinkenlight said:

```
void BaseEl::display() 
{
    cout << "P: " << priority << "\tN: " <<  name;
}
```